# float triange picture by the list

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, alignment

Here is some code, but it is not perfect, All the list elements will be not static and it need to be placed evenly by height of parent block. SO it should be good looking.
Now it is placed not through the common height of parent block, I made 50 px bttom margin

```js
$('.triangle-list1, .triangle-list2').wrapAll('<div class="triangle-list-top">');
        $('.triangle-list3, .triangle-list4').wrapAll('<div class="triangle-list-middle">');
        $('.triangle-list5, .triangle-list6').wrapAll('<div class="triangle-list-bottom">');

        $('.triangle-list:last').addClass('triangle-list-last');
```

```css
.tr {
 width: 440px;
 height: 325px;
 clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 0 100%, 100% 100%);
 background-position: center !important;
 background-size: cover !important;
 background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
 margin: 100px auto 0px;
}
.triangle-list-area {
 position: relative;
 margin-top: -337px;
 height: 450px;
}
.triangle-area {
 background-image: url("../img/circles-tr.png");
 background-position: center;
 background-size: cover;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-color: #2b2d33 !important;
}

.tr-area {
 position: relative;
 background-image: url("../img/figure-tr.png");
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.triangle-list {
 font-size: 22px;
 width: 420px;
 position: relative;
}
.triangle-list1, .triangle-list3, .triangle-list5{
 text-align: right;
}
.triangle-list-top {
 margin-bottom: 20px;
  display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
}

.triangle-list-middle {
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 /*position: relative;*/
 justify-content: space-between;
 display: flex;
}
.triangle-list-middle .triangle-list {
 width: 360px;
}
.triangle-list-bottom {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
}
.triangle-list-bottom .triangle-list {
 width: 275px;
}
.triangle-list-last {
 bottom: 0px;
 text-align: center;
 position: absolute;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translateX(-50%);
 width: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = "tr-area">
    <div class = "tr" style="background: url('https://orig00.deviantart.net/3bd9/f/2010/150/a/4/windows_pica_choo_by_yukamarie18.jpg')"></div>
        <div class = "triangle-list-area">
            <div class = 'triangle-list triangle-list1'>Element 1
            </div>
            <div class = 'triangle-list triangle-list2'>Element 2
            </div>
            <div class = 'triangle-list triangle-list3'>Element 3
            </div>
            <div class = 'triangle-list triangle-list4'>Element 4
            </div>
            <div class = 'triangle-list triangle-list5'>Element 5
            </div>
            <div class = 'triangle-list triangle-list6'>Element 6
            </div>
            <div class = 'triangle-list triangle-list6'>Element 7
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Maybe someone know how to create triangle picture and float this picture by the list.
[image]

Comment: Please show us what you've tried. I would use a larger div with CSS `background:url(triangleImg.png) center;` that contains other divs that I would `float:left;` and `float:right;` on. So I would edit your image with an image editor, using transparency.

Comment: added snippet to the question

Answer (score 0):

As for triangle - you can make it simlpy by addind borders for your specific `img` in the css file.

```css
    div#box {
      border-top: 100px solid transparent;
      border-right: 150px solid transparent;
      border-bottom: 300px solid #111;
      border-left: 150px solid transparent;
      margin: 40px;
      width: 0px;
    }
```

```html
   <div id="box"></div>
```

The answer for your second question:

To make a such layout - first of all you need to make a three column grid layout and then give the individual position for each `li` (or if you want to use `div`) element in the way is how you want to show it. Like:

```
<div>
  <div class="row__first">
    <ul>...</ul>
  </div>
  <div class="row__second">
    <div class="img__mask-triangle">
      <img>
    </div>
    <span>...</span>
  </div>
  <div class="row__third">
    <ul>...</ul>
  </div>
</div>
```